# Как сделать редирект с www на https

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть сайт `xxx.ru`. Есть его поддомен `sub.xxx.ru`. На обоих есть сертификаты ssl. Я хочу при чтобы когда мы набираем `www.sub.xxx.ru` или `www.xxx.ru` оно автоматом редиректилось на `https://..`. без `www`

Мой конфиг некорректно обрабатывает данную ситуацию

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)xxx\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%xxx.ru/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте эту конструкцию:

```
# rule for forcing www on main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rule for removing www on sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: не работаетю....

Comment: мне это в корневой папке создавать .htaccess или в папке поддомена

Comment: 2 верхние строки - на основном домене, 2 нижние на сабдоменах